# Create Web fonts using SVG

Tags: css, svg, fonts, webfonts

I am fairly new to svg and webfonts, and I have some svg logos which I would like to embed in my web page (and make sure they are visible on various device types)

I have tried the icon-font-generator (https://github.com/Workshape/icon-font-generator), to create web fonts, but I am not sure if this is the right approach or should I use img tag , i.e. `<img class="svg" src="../svg/Tensorflow_logo.svg">`

I don't want to give fixed height and width and all logos should appear of the same size. Is web fonts the right approach, and how do I need to create webfonts maintaining the original colors of the trademark logos.

Thanks,

Comment: Pros and cons: https://www.sitepoint.com/icon-fonts-vs-svg-debate/ or https://css-tricks.com/icon-fonts-vs-svg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can easily turn your **SVG** files into fonts using the
>   **[icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select)** .

1.select SVG 
[image]

2.select Color section for create color pattern

[image]

3.select and create color pattern and click Add theme button

[image]

4.select Edit icon and click on the SVG in page

[image]

5.in edit page select svg section by section and select color

[image]

- Once you have reached the desired shape, you can close the edit page

6.click on generate font and download
[image]

Comment: I used IcoMoon, works for some logos, but here is the logo which has multiple colors and I couldn't get it working. https://github.com/cloudfoundry/logos/blob/master/CF_Icon_4-colour.svg

Comment: it seems they removed the color option. I can't seem to find it there anymore!